# Custom 404 page with Silex not rendered in prod configuration

Tags: http-status-code-404, silex

I am struggling a little bit while trying to display a custom 404 error page using the **Silex** micro-framework.

My project is configured as follows:

- got an **index.php** page to run in **production** mode, loading a `prod.php` configuration file
- got an **index_dev.php** to run in **debug** mode. It uses also the `prod.php` configuration file, but some settings gets overridden by a `dev.php` file, like `$app['debug']` being set to **true**.

So basically the configuration is the same.

I have defined an error handler as follows:

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {

    // commented for testing purposes
    /*if ($app['debug']) {
        return;
    }*/

    if ($code == 404) {

        $loader = $app['dataloader'];
        $data = array(
            'global' => $loader->load('global'),
            'common' => $loader->load('common', $app['locale']),
            'header' => $loader->load('header', $app['locale']),
            'footer' => $loader->load('footer', $app['locale'])
        );

        return new Response( $app['twig']->render('404.html.twig', array( 'data' => $data )), 404);
    }

    return new Response('We are sorry, but something went terribly wrong.', $code);

});
```

When trying to access `http://localhost:8888/index_dev.php/my-non-existing-page`, I get my 404 template rendered and displayed as expected.

When trying to access `http://localhost:8888/my-non-existing-page`, my 404 template is not rendered and I get a standard 404 error page instead !

Might be difficult to help me. Feel free to ask for more details if needed. I am simply willing to understand better what is actually happening here.

Comment: What does your htaccess look like?

Comment: I have no htaccess file defined yet. Just the global configuration on my local server (using MAMP). Do you think of a specific setting ? The thing is that the homepage is displayed correctly, problem is really the error handler not displaying the custom 404 page on "prod" configuration.

Comment: I would have expected you to have an htaccess file. Here is a very basic one I use with silex projects. 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]

Comment: I guess I just needed an htaccess indeed. Make sense that it was working in "dev" mode as I specify the page index_dev.php. Thanks for the help !

Comment: no problem, I've added it as an answer now. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to rewrite requests to your index.php file. See below for a basic example to get this working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```